# Running a secondary python script from a main script

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pycharm, subprocess

I have a couple of python scripts that need to be ran from the main script.  Each script is written as stand alone code.  I don't want to use the import statement to bring the scripts into the main scripts as I'm concerned that there may be clashes between the variables, classes, etc.

I've researched how to call scripts and tried  `exec(open("Motor.py").read())`, but this doesn't pause the calling script, but does run the called (Motor.py)script.

I've also tried `result = subprocess.run(["python", "Motor.py"], capture_output=True, text=True)`, which bombs out the called script with syntax errors that don't exist when the called script is executed by the exec command or when the script is ran as stand alone.  Here is an example of what 'errors' are returned.

`CompletedProcess(args=['python', 'Motor.py'], returncode=1, stdout='', stderr='  File "Motor.py", line 68\n    self.geometry(f"{750}x{385}")\n                               ^\nSyntaxError: invalid syntax\n')`

Obviously I'm not doing something correct, but I can't figure it out.  Currently coding it in python 3.

Comment: `python` likely refers to a different Python interpreter than the one you're using in the main script (likely a Python 2 interpreter?). You should use `sys.executable` as the first entry in command list passed to `subprocess.run` to make sure you're using the same interpreter.

Comment: Avoid using secondary scripts. A more "Python-ish" way of doing this is to use modules. Like, make a motor module and put your code in a function / object and then invoke it. Using subscripts leads to messy code and a lot of errors depending on the runtime (like, the python executable name, etc...). To avoid conflict between variables when using import, just put your secondary code in a function, named motor for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the subprocess module and Popen, which will open a process you can await for.

```
import subprocess

cmd = [sys.executable, 'Motor.py']
subprocess.Popen(cmd).wait()
```

Comment: Results in this error:    File "Motor.py", line 68
    self.geometry(f"{750}x{385}")
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Just changed it to this and it works.  ` cmd = [sys.executable, 'Motor.py']
        subprocess.Popen(cmd).wait()`.  Thanks Lucas and Brian.

Comment: Update the answer with teh correction!